# VPN via IPSec on iOS with manual DNS

Tags: ios, network, vpn, dns

I want to configure a VPN via IPSec for Mac and iOS. I need to set a manual DNS-server with a local adress of the destination network.

On Mac this is easy. Just setup a new VPN, then click Advanced at there you go. You can enter the DNS-server and search domains if necessary. I tested it and it worked perfectly.

On iOS this seems impossible. There is no such option in the VPN settings (iOS 14). I also tried to use Configurator 2 (Version 2.7.1 is the latest I can use with my old MacBook) for creating a profile. However, there are just the same options as in the VPN settings on the device itself.

I want to use the VPN via the mobile network and for mobile networks aren't any DNS options either.

How can I set up the DNS-Server?

Comment: I use IPSec VPN on demand on my iPhone, and looking up the settings in the mobileconfig file, there indeed is no DNS server setting. It seems like the DNS settings for the remote network are automatically retrieved from the VPN server upon connection.